# Finding training data for tweets with labels: positive, negative, neutral

Tags: python, label, training-data, naivebayes, corpus

Are there any training data of tweets with labels: positive, negative, neutral as following:

"tweet 1" positive
"tweet 2" positive
"tweet 3" neutral
"tweet 4" negative

Or in general are there any good site for finding training sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find good training datasets on kaggle!

A good example would be the [Sentiment140 dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kazanova/sentiment140) with over 1.6 million tweets. They have been annotated with (0 = negative, 4 = positive) - but it's explained on-site! :)

Comment: Do you know how I can clear the csv file so that I only have: 0 the tweet, 1 the tweet and so on?

Comment: There are various tools to do so - but this should belong into a seperate question, I suppose. I would suggest `pandas` - read it as a dataframe and then manipulate it the way you like.

Comment: I tried to use pandas but dont know why it did not work

Comment: Can you post a separate question with the concrete problem you are facing? Post the code you tried, what you want to achieve and what happened!

Comment: yes I will do it